# Android - Some way to start Firebase Messasing (FCM) with activity?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, push, firebase-cloud-messaging

Some way to start Firebase Messasing (FCM) with activity?
I'm see that sometimes it stops working randomly (this is serious and there has not been a significant change in the example code of the Google).

So I would like to start it in several possible events, to ensure its operation.
I find it strange that an official application fails so badly.
Receiving notification was supposed to be simple.

Works perfectly until you stop randomly, the application does not crash. I navigate through the application, close and open and no message arrives, then when I turn on and off the wifi the messages arrive.

Comment: How are you sending the messages? Are you looking to send messages in the foreground or background? Can you update your question to include this information, as well as your code for receiving messages?

Answer (score 1):

The messages in Notifications have a little unpredictable behaviour for FCM. But it is nothing to worry about. Most (>99%) of Firebase notifications are delivered in less than 1 second. But occasionally for really small volumes in apps that are 'under development' on 'in experiment' you will find unexplained delays in delivery times of the notifications. I suspect this is because the FCM Servers prioritise the delivery queue. Nothing much to worry about. Keep on developing your app and you will find that more notifications you deliver using FCM, the more reliable it starts to become.